# NHibernate include/exclude all

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

I'm building a complex security mechanism to filter access to objects depending on various rights.

As part of this I want to have an initial `OR` in my query that excludes all possible results from the query before the permissions allow access to certain subsets. In SQL it would look like this:

```
select   *
from     Table
where    (1 = 0)
or       ( /* various predicates */ )
```

However, I'm not sure how to create that initial `1 = 0` through the criteria API. I will probably need to create `1 = 1` at some point too but I'm assuming that will be a similar task.

How do I do this?

Comment: Initial thought is I might have to implement my own criterion which I'm looking at now.

Comment: You might want to look into Rhino Security, it seems to cover what you are trying to achieve. http://github.com/ayende/rhino-security

Comment: Yeah we've used that as inspiration but we need something different enough to write our own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tuna Toksoz](http://twitter.com/tehlike/statuses/5450823423) has suggested this method which is simple and clear:

```
var stuff = session.CreateCriteria<Stuff>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Constant(1), 0))
    .List<Stuff>();
```

Comment: but if you add more criteria with Add() they will actually AND with the 1=0

Comment: Yes, but you would use it with a disjunction or similar. I'm just demonstrating the technique for achieving a criterion that eliminates all results.